# Totally ordered Ord instance for directionless Edge?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create an instance of a data type for a directionless edge.
Edge 1 2 == Edge 2 1 (i.e. Edge from 1 to 2 is the same as Edge from 2 to 1, direction doesn't matter).

Here's an example of of the data type, and Eq instance and an attempt at an Ord instance:

```
data Edge = Edge Int Int deriving Show
instance Eq Edge where
    (Edge x1 y1) == (Edge x2 y2) = ((x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) || (x1 == y2 && y1 == x2))
instance Ord Edge where
    compare e1@(Edge x1 y1) e2@(Edge x2 y2) = if e1 == e2 
                                              then EQ 
                                              else ????
```

Any idea how to get a [totally ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) Ord instance in this case?

Comment: If this is for a graph data-type, then the usual approach is to represent each undirected edge as two directed half-edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is similar to Thomas's, except I recommend that you normalize when you construct the edge.

```
mkEdge :: Int -> Int -> Edge
mkEdge x y | x <= y    = Edge x y
           | otherwise = Edge y x
```

Now you know that the vertex with the smaller index appears first, and the `deriving (Eq, Ord)` instances will do exactly what you want.  You just have to make sure you only create edges with the `mkEdge` "smart constructor" (you can do this by putting `Edge` in a module and not exporting the `Edge` constructor).

Comment: The more general principle here is to have a 1 to 1 mapping between your denotations and representations; i.e. don't have two different objects representing the same thing.  Working with equivalence classes is often very difficult (though occasionally it is necessary).

Answer (score 2):

Just think of the vertices the edge connects as unordered sets
(coincidentally of cardinallity 2) instead of two individual elements
in an arbitrary order:

```
instance Ord Edge where
  compare e1@(Edge x1 y1) e2@(Edge x2 y2) = compare (sort [x1,y1]) (sort [x2,y2])
```

Or even use actual sets:

```
data EdgeS = EdgeS (Set Int) deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord EdgeS where
    compare (EdgeS a) (EdgeS b) = compare a b
```

And this instance can even be derived (as for `Eq`).  If you'd like, you can make a special constructor:

```
mkEdge : Int -> Int -> EdgeS
mkEdge a b = EdgeS (S.fromList [a,b])
```

And some tests:

```
> compare (mkEdge 1 2) (mkEdge 2 1)
EQ
> compare (mkEdge 1 2) (mkEdge 3 1)
LT
> compare (mkEdge 1 2) (mkEdge 1 3)
LT
```